# Throwing new error in catch block doesn't work

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, throw

I'm doing some async operations, and I'm using the native implementation of Promise to control the execution flow:

```
Promise.resolve({})
   .then(...)
   .then(...)
   .then(...)
   .catch((error) => { throw new Error(error) });
```

No error is being thrown, but when I changed to a console.log, everything worked. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is being thrown but you're not catching it afterwards.

Comment: Where do you expect the error to be caught? Are you trying to catch it *synchronously* with a `try..catch` around this `Promise` chain? That won't work, since the promise is *asynchronous*…

Comment: You should see an unhandled rejection in your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception raised in a promise chain can only be intercepted with a catch later in the same promise chain. It cannot be seen outside of the promise chain (if this was your intent.) In your example, the exception is "lost". However, Chrome and some other browsers detect this case and put a warning for an unhandled exception in the console.

A correct promise chain with exceptions would be:

```
Promise.resolve({})
   .then(...)
   .then(() => { throw new Error(error); }) // throw exception here
   .then(...) 
   .catch((error) => { /* handle error */ }); // catch it later in promise chain
   .then(...)
   .then(() => { throw new Error(error); }) // this exception is not caught later in the promise and is lost (shown as unhandled exception in some browsers)
```

Comment: Not exactly lost, you can [handle it globally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunhandledrejection) as well.